# The implementation of random_device in VS2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, random, c++11

From my reading of the standard, `random_device::entropy()` should return 0.0 if a software engine is used. However, in VS2010 it returns 32.0, which in my understanding requires hardware to produce non-deterministic random numbers.

How does VS2010's `random_device` generate the number sequence?

Comment: Well, it is a bit naughty.  But it uses SystemFunction036() from advapi.dll to generate cryptographically secure random numbers.

Comment: @HansPassant: cryptographically secure still doesn't mean non-deterministic, right?

Comment: @HansPassant isn't a cryptographically secure random number by definition HW generated? (even if it is a combination of momentary system parameters)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to a comment left on this question by Hans Passant, `random_device` uses `advapi32:SystemFunction036`, which  according to MSDN is an alias for `RtlGenRandom`.  This is verified by the runtime library source provided with VC++ 2010:

`random_device::operator()()` in `<random>` calls the following chain of functions:

```
_Random_device() // in xrngdev.cpp
    rand_s()     // in rand_s.c
        RtlGenRandom()/SystemFunction036()  // in advapi32.dll
```

According to a comment left by Michael Howard on one of his blog articles, ["Cryptographically Secure Random number on Windows without using CryptoAPI"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/michael_howard/cryptographically-secure-random-number-on-windows-without-using-cryptoapi), `RtlGenRandom` uses the following:

> The RNG generates as specified in FIPS 186-2 appendix 3.1 with SHA-1
> as the G function. With entropy from:
>
> - The current process ID (GetCurrentProcessID).
> - The current thread ID (GetCurrentThreadID).
> - The ticks since boot (GetTickCount).
> - The current time (GetLocalTime).
> - Various high-precision performance counters (QueryPerformanceCounter).
> - An MD4 hash of the user's environment block, which includes username, computer name, and search path. MD4 is a hashing algorithm
>   that creates a 128-bit message digest from input data to verify data
>   integrity.
> - High-precision internal CPU counters, such as RDTSC, RDMSR, RDPMC
> - Low-level system information: Idle Process Time, Io Read Transfer Count, I/O Write Transfer Count, I/O Other Transfer Count, I/O Read
>   Operation Count, I/O Write Operation Count, I/O Other Operation Count,
>   Available Pages, Committed Pages, Commit Limit, Peak Commitment, Page
>   Fault Count, Copy On Write Count, Transition Count, Cache Transition
>   Count, Demand Zero Count, Page Read Count, Page Read I/O Count, Cache
>   Read Count, Cache I/O Count, Dirty Pages Write Count, Dirty Write I/O
>   Count, Mapped Pages Write Count, Mapped Write I/O Count, Paged Pool
>   Pages, Non Paged Pool Pages, Paged Pool Allocated space, Paged Pool
>   Free space, Non Paged Pool Allocated space, Non Paged Pool Free space,
>   Free System page table entry, Resident System Code Page, Total System
>   Driver Pages, Total System Code Pages, Non Paged Pool Lookaside Hits,
>   Paged Pool Lookaside Hits, Available Paged Pool Pages, Resident System
>   Cache Page, Resident Paged Pool Page, Resident System Driver Page,
>   Cache manager Fast Read with No Wait, Cache manager Fast Read with
>   Wait, Cache manager Fast Read Resource Missed, Cache manager Fast Read
>   Not Possible, Cache manager Fast Memory Descriptor List Read with No
>   Wait, Cache manager Fast Memory Descriptor List Read with Wait, Cache
>   manager Fast Memory Descriptor List Read Resource Missed, Cache
>   manager Fast Memory Descriptor List Read Not Possible, Cache manager
>   Map Data with No Wait, Cache manager Map Data with Wait, Cache manager
>   Map Data with No Wait Miss, Cache manager Map Data Wait Miss, Cache
>   manager Pin-Mapped Data Count, Cache manager Pin-Read with No Wait,
>   Cache manager Pin Read with Wait, Cache manager Pin-Read with No Wait
>   Miss, Cache manager Pin-Read Wait Miss, Cache manager Copy-Read with
>   No Wait, Cache manager Copy-Read with Wait, Cache manager Copy-Read
>   with No Wait Miss, Cache manager Copy-Read with Wait Miss, Cache
>   manager Memory Descriptor List Read with No Wait, Cache manager Memory
>   Descriptor List Read with Wait, Cache manager Memory Descriptor List
>   Read with No Wait Miss, Cache manager Memory Descriptor List Read with
>   Wait Miss, Cache manager Read Ahead IOs, Cache manager Lazy-Write IOs,
>   Cache manager Lazy-Write Pages, Cache manager Data Flushes, Cache
>   manager Data Pages, Context Switches, First Level Translation buffer
>   Fills, Second Level Translation buffer Fills, and System Calls.
> - System exception information consisting of Alignment Fix up Count, Exception Dispatch Count, Floating Emulation Count, and Byte Word
>   Emulation Count.
> - System lookaside information consisting of Current Depth, Maximum Depth, Total Allocates, Allocate Misses, Total Frees, Free Misses,
>   Type, Tag, and Size.
> - System interrupt information consisting of context switches, deferred procedure call count, deferred procedure call rate, time
>   increment, deferred procedure call bypass count, and asynchronous
>   procedure call bypass count.
> - System process information consisting of Next Entry Offset, Number Of Threads, Create Time, User Time, Kernel Time, Image Name, Base
>   Priority, Unique Process ID, Inherited from Unique Process ID, Handle
>   Count, Session ID, Page Directory Base, Peak Virtual Size, Virtual
>   Size, Page Fault Count, Peak Working Set Size, Working Set Size, Quota
>   Peak Paged Pool Usage, Quota Paged Pool Usage, Quota Peak Non Paged
>   Pool Usage, Quota Non Paged Pool Usage, Page file Usage, Peak Page
>   file Usage, Private Page Count, Read Operation Count, Write Operation
>   Count, Other Operation Count, Read Transfer Count, Write Transfer
>   Count, and Other Transfer Count.

There's a full explanation (including diagrams) in Chapter 8 of Writing Secure Code, 2nd Edition.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's a bug, maybe it isn't.  But it sure looks deliberate.  From Microsoft's [own documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982250.aspx):

> The class describes a source of random numbers, preferably from a
>   non-deterministic external device. **In this implementation the values
>   produced by default are not non-deterministic.** They are uniformly
>   distributed in the closed range [0, 65535].

And from the C++11 standard, section 26.5.6.6 on `random_device`:

> `result_type operator()();`
>
> Returns: **A non-deterministic random value**,
>   uniformly distributed between min() and max(), inclusive. It is
>   implementation-defined how these values are generated.

By a strict reading of the standard, they shouldn't be able return anything other than 0 from `entropy()`.  Perhaps they plan to improve the implementation someday and tried to make it do Something Reasonable for now.  They do have an API call to generate [cryptographically secure random numbers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but don't appear to be using it for this yet.

Comment: So, in other words, they're _already_ lying. Makes a mockery of having `random_device::entropy()` in the first place. Hate.

Comment: i.e. it's _definitely_ a bug then, albeit a deliberate one (making it worse)

Comment: Come on guys, it's easy to hate MS but I think this might just be a non-deliberate mistake. Besides, compared to the old days their C++ compiler is much better. They started supporting C++0x before the standard was even finalised. Any idea how `random_device` generates its sequence, and why the range is so small?