# How std::random_device is implemented

Tags: c++, random

I tested the following mini example with MSVC 2017 on Win7:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::cout << "entropy: " << rd.entropy() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

To my surprise, it outputs "entropy: 32". This means that rd produces real-random numbers instead of pseudo-random numbers. I was expecting "entropy: 0". As far as I understand it, no finite-length code is capable of producing real-random numbers, it takes a real specially-designed physical device to do so. No such device is attached to my testing PC.

My question is: how std::random_device is implemented that it produces real-random number without special hardware support?

Comment: [here's one impl](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/random.cc.html), and some [more random info](http://www.pcg-random.org/posts/cpps-random_device.html)

Comment: @gman it seems that magic is done by "__x86_rdrand(void)",

Comment: The question seems to already have an answer for a previous VC++ version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549357/the-implementation-of-random-device-in-vs2010

Comment: The standard says if the system has a nondeterministic random number source then the implementation of `std::random_device` should use it. Many `OS`s have access to physical random sources through the physical device interfaces.

Comment: At least one major implementation swiped [an XKCD comic](https://xkcd.com/221/).

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, are you *sure* there is no specially-designed physical device in your PC?  Intel added such hardware to the CPU in 2013, and AMD followed suit in 2015.

---

Secondly, it is possible to acquire reasonably good entropyby measuring the jitter in timings from physical processes like

- network packets
- hard disk (less useful if the hard disk is an SSD)
- mouse movements
- keyboard clicks

For a desktop or laptop, acquiring good entropy is really not that hard.  Where it becomes more *challenging* is in constrained environments like a smartcard or an IoT device at first boot (where there have not been many network packets - but you want to generate a good public/private key pair).